# Intellij issue in recognizing submodules of multi module maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a pom.xml which have multi sub modules

```
<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
</modules>
```

when I right click in each submodules pom.xml and add as maven project, there are tons of maven dependency errors that are created in intellij. and there are compile errors as well
Have been trying lot of things but to no avail. Added project as maven module but cant get it through

Comment: Close the project in IntelliJ. Delete the `.idea` directory... and import the project from the root pom into IntellIj... IDEA will handle the import of the modules automatically...

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your parent Project's pom.xml (File -> Open -> Navigate to the Project's folder -> Double-click pom.xml) - IDEA should automatically parse it and pick up all of its' sub-Projects.

If you try to add the sub-Project by right-clicking their pom.xmls IDEA will attempt to add them as standalone Projects, which very well may result in the behavior you've described.